# Merge variables in yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

I'm writing my docker compose file and I want to parametrize it.
But I don't want to use `.env` files (already used to pass keys).
The initial file :

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  service1:
    image: image1
    environment:
      PORT: '5000'
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: path_to_creds
    expose:
      - 5000
  service2:
    image: image2
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_IP:-127.0.0.1}:80:8050"
    environment:
      PORT: '8050'
  service3:
    image: image2
    ports:
      - "${SERVER_IP:-127.0.0.1}:80:8050"
    environment:
      PORT: '8050'
      GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: path_to_creds
```

Following [this page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields), I've make this docker-compose.yaml :

```yaml
version: '3.7'

# an app
x-api: &a1
  image: image1
  environment:
    PORT: '5000'
  expose:
    - 5000

# another
x-web: &a2
  image: image2
  ports:
    - "${SERVER_IP:-127.0.0.1}:80:8050"
  environment:
    PORT: '8050'

# some more envs
x-gcp: &gcp
  environment:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: path_to_creds


services:
  service1:
    <<: [*gcp, *a1]
  service2:
    <<: *a2
  service3:
    <<: [*gcp, *a2]
```

But I have an issue this the `enviromnent` key:
In brief:

```yaml
A: &a
    k:
    a: 1

B: &b
    k:
    b: 2

C:
    <<: [*b, *a]
```

Result in :

```yaml
C:
  k:
    b: 2
```

and not :

```yaml
C:
  k:
    a: 1
    b: 2
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use `.env`. It's exactly for that. `env_files:` don't have effect on port definitions in your yml, you have to use `.env`

Comment: You cannot merge arrays in YAML. Besides that, what you are doing just makes the docker-compose file less readable. I recommend you use anchors and `x-*` directives sparingly.

Comment: I guess the problem here is that [YAML merge keys](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), as per spec, are not performing a deep merge, but just the top layer. So you can't use it for that.